# mocha test i18n TypeError: Cannot read property 'text50' of undefined

Tags: node.js, internationalization, mocha.js

I am using mocha test framework for testing my application and for translation i am using i18n from mashpie.
In my validation.js file, i require i18n module and use i18n.__ function like

`console.log(i18n.__('text50'));`

In my test file validation.test.js i require validation.js for testing. Then i run the test with mocha, as results i got.

```
Running "mochaTest:test" (mochaTest) task
>> Mocha exploded!
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'text50' of undefined
>>     at translate (/Volumes/Develop/townspeech/node_modules/i18n/i18n.js:355:23)
>>     at Object.i18nTranslate [as __] (/Volumes/Develop/townspeech/node_modules/i18n/i18n.js:96:11)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Develop/townspeech/server/libs/validation.js:24:18)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>     at require (module.js:380:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Develop/townspeech/server/controllers/new_password.js:10:18)
Warning: Task "mochaTest:test" failed. Used --force, continuing.
```

But when i try

```
node validation.js
```

as output i have got the text, not the error. Why when i do testing, i got the error and execute as usual not?

Comment: Enable i18 logging in your tests: `DEBUG=i18n:* mocha -g {name of test that fails}`. If the logs were not helpful enough, then create a small test-case to reproduce the problem and post the full source code and i18n logs here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for the sake of others, here is the solution that worked for me:

Most probably it is the location of the locale directory.
Check if the location of the locate directory, configured in i18n.configure, is relative.

You run from different location when executing node and when executing mocha tests, hence i18n fails to find the locale folder.